# Node-red users vs flows

Tags: node-red

How can I bind different 
node-auth users to specific flows or tabs?

I succeeded to set more users with own login credentials, I would like to bind each to a different flow or even dashboard tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer, you can not.

Node-RED is not a true multi-user environment. The only option is read-only vs read-write access to the flow editor.

Comment: See,  editor is already protected by admin-auth. 
Thanks indeed hardilib.